# Nested FormArray in Angular 4?

Tags: forms, angular, reactive, formarray

Hey need help with reactive forms in Angular 4. I've got the next FormGroup declared:

```
userForm:FormGroup = new FormGroup ({
    employeenumber: new FormControl(),
    name: new FormControl(),
    lastname: new FormControl(),
    birthdate: new FormControl(),
    phone: new FormControl(),
    email: new FormControl(),
    username: new FormControl(),
    password: new FormControl(),
    blocked: new FormControl(),
    departments: new FormArray([
        new FormControl()
    ])
});
```

But I want to nest other array inside the departments array. To have something like this:

```
departments: [
    { department: 'test', roles:['rol1', 'rol2'] }
]
```

It is possible to nest FormArrays? or what is the best way of doing this.

Comment: yes, its possible, you can see the angular reactive form document

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for something like this [**Nested Reactive Forms**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive).

There a [**Highly Nested one too**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-nested-reactive-form) if you wish .

I couldn't place the whole code here as it is too long and your question wanted to check if it is possible to nest Form Array.Hope this helps

Comment: Useful links, but lacking examples of nesting components with nested FormArrays.

Comment: Ya jack only stand alone stuff